# How to upload an XML file using multipart/form-data with Restsharp?

Tags: c#, rest, multipartform-data, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

**Question:** How to upload an XML file using multipart/form-data with Restsharp?

**Problem:**

I'm using Peppol for sending invoices using the Codabox API.
I want to upload an xml to the rest service. 
The rest service itself is under control by the provider Codabox.
I have 2 methods provided who I expect to do the same.

First of all with Postman and httpclient, all the things works fine.
I want to get the same from the httpclient method working using the restsharp way.

RestSharp version: 106.2.1

> **Error message with Restsharp**
>
> response = "StatusCode: BadRequest, Content-Type: application/json,
>   Content-Length: -1)" Content = "{\"file\":[\"No file was
>   submitted.\"]}"

For realizing this I have an X-Software-Company key in the header, providing a valid xml file that I send using form-data (multipart/form-data) and my authentication credentials.

**Expected solution:**

I want to get the Restsharp method working and why it now doesn't work.
So the Restsharp method I provided need to do the same as the httpclient method I provided.

**What I have tried:**

**Restsharp method:** ==> here is the problem

```
  public void TestUpload()
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.xml");

        var client = new RestClient("url for the rest call");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        request.AddHeader("X-Software-Company", "software key");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        request.AddFile("file", @"C:\temp\test.xml");
        //request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        //request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"C:\\temp\\test.xml\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```

**HttpClient method:** ==> it works fine

```
public void TestUploadHttpClient()
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.xml");

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "credentials");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Software-Company", "software key");
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"))
            {
                content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileBytes)), "file", "test.xml");

                using (var message = httpClient.PostAsync("url for the rest call", content).Result)
                {
                    var input = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Postman generated code:**

If I do the request by Postman there is no problem, if I check the Restsharp code generated by postman it gives me:

```
var client = new RestClient("url for the rest call");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic credentials");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddHeader("X-Software-Company", "software key");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"C:\\temp\\test.xml\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I have exactly the code tested generated from postman but it doesn't work.

**EDIT 2018-03-19:** 
Possible issue in RestSharp: [Added files not being recieved #1079](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1079)

**Temporary solution:**

I'm using RestSharp version v105.2.3 then it works like a charm.

Have anyone an idea why the restsharp method does not work and how to solve that?

Comment: Do you need to receive it in an xml format? If you need to receive an xml format try to add on the headers an Accept header with the value application/xml, and btw if you are programming your backend, you need to create an output formatter for that or use the one that the framework provides like(XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter)

Comment: No, I want to upload an xml to the rest service. The rest service itself is under control by the provider Codabox. I have in this case no control over that backend. But with postman and httpclient i have no problems.

Comment: Well try to see what is the code that postman sends and see what you have left

Comment: I have my question updated with the postman code but this also doesn't work.

Comment: in the http client I see you posting the stream data of the xml file.  in the restsharp example i see you reading fileBytes, but I dont see you posting the data...

Comment: @Keith Aymar We have tested multiple methods but the addfile(restsharp example) method searches for the file and read also the file. We have also tried another way that not reads the file automatically that we needed to read it before. But both gave me the same BadRequest error. So that line of code(byte[] fileBytes) is not necessary for that restsharp way. I had it used for an other way without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the content type parameter in the AddFile method, like this:

```
request.AddFile("file", @"C:\temp\test.xml", "application/octet-stream");
```