# Response from webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.forms, postman

I am consuming a web service made in php, I have already answered from Postman I get data, but when doing the implementation in C # through RestSharp, I get a connection but I do not get content.

Try in a Xamarin App and in a Console App, but I can not get the content.

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://www.test.com/app/ws.php/");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"reqedu\"\r\n\r\nget-data-alum\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"appusr\"\r\n\r\nuser\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"apppwd\"\r\n\r\npassword\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the execute method, you need  check response code whether the request is successful or not from response object something like this

```
  IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
  if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
      Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
  else
      Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks i´m using the debbuger to do that, but i only get [  ] without data

Comment: may be restsharp issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323115/how-to-upload-an-xml-file-using-multipart-form-data-with-restsharp